MacOS Changing typing language CAPS LOCK turns off
When i switch keyboard language (i am not changing language using caps lock) between ENG and GR (or anything else) and i have the caps lock on after the switch the caps lock turns off.
So Typing ENG or GR with CAPS LOCK ON
switching language GR or ENG
CAPS LOCK off
I want to find a way to remain the caps lock ON after my switch between typing languages.
Do you have any ideas, i searched the entire web and found nothing.
